# python 3.6.1 'FOR LOOP'

Tags: python

[python using for loop.......][1]

whether this is possible using 'for loop'???????....`

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLZmZ.png

```
 n=int(input())
for j in range (0,n):
      for i in range (1+j,0):
        print(' ',end='#')
     print()
```

`
Help me to solve this using 'for' loop....
i don't think it is possible in 'while' loop. if possible please post that also..
But ultimately i need this only by "FOR LOOP"...

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: check image.....

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i need this as output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLZmZ.png

Comment: @Killer Death https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLZmZ.png

Comment: Try the code I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
import sys
for j in range (0,n):
      for i in range (n-j+1):
        sys.stdout.write(' ');
      for k in range (j+1):
        sys.stdout.write('#');
      print()
```

Comment: sys.stdout not defined